# how to find if a list of elements is in another list of elements?

Tags: python, list, text, replace, element

I have uploaded a text file as file_contents. the aim of this is to calculate the words appeared in my text file after removing punctuations and some "uninteresting words". Below is my code:

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
# Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
"we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
"their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
"have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
"all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
# LEARNER CODE START HERE

file_list = file_contents.split() #split words into individual string

for word in file_list:
    word= word.lower()#small letter

    if word in uninteresting_words:
        word = word.replace(word,"")
        return word
    if word in punctuations:
        word = word.replace(word,"")
        return word
print (word)

#create a dictionary
#add those words if they are not in dictionary , and count+1 for value
dict={}
n=0
for x in word:
    if x not in dict:
        n=1
        dict[x]=n
    else:
        n+=1
        dict[x]=n
    return dict
print(dict)
```

calculate_frequencies(file_contents)

the result shows '' . may i know what is wrong with my code

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code ? Give sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: I want to remove all the punctuations and uninteresting_words and produce a list of words. sorry it looks confusing, i will edit my code

Comment: Try removing both the `return word` lines.

Comment: Proper indentation will help, dont know where your function ends.

Comment: i just edit the post. I tried to remove but only got the list "word" only show one word, which is impossble because my text file has many words

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your script in this way:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

# Remove punctuation from file_content
file_content = file_content.translate(str.maketrans("", "", punctuation))
# Get words
words = file_content.split()
# Keep only some words
words = [word for word in words if word not in uninteresting_words]
# Create the dictionary
d = Counter(words)
```